# SSRS 12.0.0.0 upgrade to SSRS 13.0.0.0

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

i am having application which is already working with `SSRS 12.0.0.0` version i want to upgrade it now to `13.0.0.0` for that i have added new `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms` version reference which is 13.0.0.0 in the application and done all required version fixing in web.config

When i am running the application and opening the page which is going to show report getting this error

[image]

i have already done the changes which are asked in the Error still getting same issue, is there something which i missed.

please help me

Comment: Have you recycled app pools/restarted iis services etc?

Comment: yes i tried everything and this i  am trying on localhost